# Post-synthesis simulation error: unable to find ports due to flattening 2D array ports to 1D

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, vivado, synthesis

In post-synthesis simulation on Vivado, the netlist flattens a 2D array to a 1D array.  How can we adapt the testbench to the change of these ports? For example in DUT instantiation, feeding values to this port through `$fscanf` function.

Example:

```
reg signed [13-1:0] mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs [1:0];
```

This port is now flattened in the netlist to `mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs[0][12:0]` and `mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs[1][12:0]`

I tried searching online for the error, but trials stated there were in vain.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we adapt the testbench to the change of these ports?

A common approach is to use the `` `ifdef `` compiler directive to make different port connections to your DUT instance in the testbench.  Here is a *pseudocode* example:

```
`ifdef GATES
    .mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs[0] ( mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs[0] ),
    .mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs[1] ( mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs[1] ),
`else
    .mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs    ( mac_ofdIsymbol_tqs ),
`endif
```

The post-synthesis simulation is run using a macro named `GATES`.  Many simulators allow you to pass an argument to the simulation command such as `+define+GATES`.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 22.6:

```
`ifdef, `else, `elsif, `endif , `ifndef
```

Also refer to your Vivado documentation on running simulation with different compiler options.